# Selection of a proper char based on the given index number. Switch-statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

There are 3 different chars, e.g. "a", "b" and "c". I need to assign the value "a" to indexes 1, 4, 7, etc., the value "b" to 2, 5, 8, etc, and the value "c" to 3, 6, 9, etc. Now imagine that the index is equal to 11. I should define the char to which it corresponds. How can I do this in JAVA? PS. I need it for the Switch-statement.

Update#1:

I thought that maybe possible solution could be the following: Take the given number, e.g. 11. Divide it by 3, because there are 3 possible choices, i.e. "a", "b" and "c". 11/3 = 3.6(6). And then if the whole part can be divided by 3 without the remainder, then estimate how may 3s it includes. In our exaple it's 1. And finally 1+round(0.66) = 2. So, the value "b" should be selected. But this solution requires using the recursion.

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: What's the spec? What should be the character associated to any integer? That's not obvious from your examples. Please refine your question.

Comment: So what happens if the index is 11? Clarify this part: "I should define the char to which it corresponds." How do you define it? Any example code you have so far that will help us understand your problem better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Java's [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator:**

```
switch (i%3) {
    case 0: return 'c';
    case 1: return 'a';
    case 2: return 'b';
    default: //
}
```

Compacted with `return`s for brevity. In real life please `break;` between independent cases.

Comment: Yes, it works if the spec is “3, 6, 9... => c”, not “3, 6, 8... => c”.

Comment: You still need to decide whether you want a `char` (`'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`) or a `String` (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`).

Comment: @ChrisJ I assumed the OP mistyped.

Comment: yes I suppose this too. Just making this clear, just in case.

Comment: Yes,sorry,I made a mistake in the thread. It's corrected now.

Comment: @paislee: Perfect. Thanks. Elegant and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(index % 3) {
    case 0:
        myChar = 'a';
        break;
    case 1:
        myChar = 'b';
        break;
    case 2:
        myChar = 'c';
        break;
    default:
        //...        
}
```

Comment: This solution is not generic enough. What if I have 100... No, I'm searching for some generic approach, otherwise I could do this myself in 1 minute:)

Comment: BTW, sorry I made a mistake in the thread -> 3,6,9. I corrected it. Perhaps, that's why you proposed such solution.